# No you cannot delete this record, rails 4.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to, at controller level say, if a role you are trying to delete == Administrator, then do not allow the user to delete that role.

I can in the view, just take away the delete link for deleting roles, but that doesn't help at controller or even model level.

Whats a way to deal with this in Rails (4.0.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that with a `before_filter`. A `before_filter` runs before the action.

So in your controller you can add:

```
before_filter :ensure_not_administrator, only: :destroy

#your actions go here

private

def ensure_not_administator
  @record = Model.find(params[:id])
  if @record.role == 'Administrator'
    flash[:error] = "Cannot delete this record"
    redirect_to where_you_want_to_go_path
    return false
  end
end
```